# PHP Page Generation Times - IIS 7.5 + PHP + FastCGI + Invision Power Board 3

Tags: php, fastcgi

I have an forum running invision power board 3 which has page generation times of just under 5 seconds. I have enabled wincache. Is there anything else I can do to increase the responsiveness of this application under PHP + FastCGI? Can we use IIS Output Caching?

Unfortunately the forums are referenced by a non-named querystring value like so: /forums/index.php?/forum/1-forum-name/ so I haven't worked out a way to get Output Caching to work with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've currently turned out Output Caching for Query String Variable(s): * with a duration of 30 seconds which seems to help.

UPDATE: Unfortunately we cannot use Output Caching everywhere as this also caches the interstitial pages after user login, etc, which quotes the user name.

We found this was due to an issue with the way invision upgrades its database schema and wrote about it here: [IPB 3 (Invision Power Board) slow loading after upgrade](http://solutionevangelist.com/discussion/18/ipb-3-invision-power-board-slow-loading-after-upgrade).